# Simple question about circles.

Tags: circles

Let's say I have a set $S=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2=1\}$. I want to prove that for every $i \in [-1,1]$ there's a point $(i,y) \in S$.

I know this sounds pretty trivial, but I need this fact for a another proof and I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: for every $i\in[-1;1]$ there at least one point $(i,\sqrt{1-i^2})$.

Answer (score 1):

For $i\in [-1,1]$, we have $1-i^2 \ge 0$. Let $y = \pm \sqrt{1-i^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $i \in [-1,1]$ then
$$
(i,\sin(\mathrm{arcos}(i))).
$$